# Solutions for Snoot Modifier Overheating Tungsten Light?

Tags: equipment-damage, equipment-protection, lighting-modifiers, lights

I'd like to use a [snoot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snoot) light modifier on an halogen light, though it's clearly causing the bulb to overheat. This is to the point of seeing smoke coming out of the light's body.

I suspect the snoot encases the light too tightly for the amount of heat the bulb spreads.

In your experience, is there a way to achieve the snoot effect without excessive overheat on the same equipment? I am wondering if there are snoots around with a larger encasement but the same attachment measure?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are a little limited here. Snoots, by their design, are heat-prone and are really only suitable for strobe lighting as a result (though they are seeing an upsurge in the LED lighting space because LEDs are much cooler). In fact, the snoot you bought specifically states that it's made for strobe monolights, not continuous lighting. The manufacturer of my snoot even states that continuously operating the snoot with a 100w modeling lamp could result in damage to the equipment.

Your ultimate problem with snoots is airflow, and it will be difficult to have enough air to cool a halogen bulb while also preventing light spill.

The obvious and cheapest option is to reduce the duty cycle to prevent overheating. This is somewhat limited though given how fast halogens heat up and how long it will take to cool. Unfortunately, you might still have issues because halogens do require being at their operating temperature to be stable in color and output.

A second option is to rig up a fan that blows across the opening at such an angle that you create a vortex inside the snoot so a lot of air can enter an exit through the small opening, but this will be tricky to accomplish and maintain. You will also probably need to limit the duty cycle to a couple of minutes at a time. (with 10-15 minutes off to cool.)

Finally, unless you are shooting video, in which case continuous lighting is required, consider switching to strobes. The mid range 500w halogen lamp output is a little over 9000 lumens. So at a shutter speed of 1/100s you're only netting 90 lumenseconds of light for your image. On the other side, a small 50w speed light will product 40ish lumenseconds per watt AND dump that entire output in a fraction of a second. So you're getting the full 2000 lumenseconds during your 1/100s exposure time. An inexpensive $50-75usd monolight will not only solve your heat issue, but provide you with about 20 times as much light to work with, which is going to be a huge help if you're using modified that block a great deal of that output.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed and competent answer.

Is there a more specific recommendation for strobe that you can make? I mean brand or model if you have anything in mind. It would give me a good starting point for resarch.

Comment: @AlexF. try this: https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=continuous+vs+strobe

Comment: Halogen lights also take a dim view towards short duty cycles since it interferes with the halogenide cycle protecting the filament against an early demise due to its higher operating temperature.

Comment: @LightBender I would still appreciate a nudge in regards of what models to look at at. I am unable to find anything interesting for the price range you have mentioned. So it might be interesting to see if you had something specific in mind.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a cookie**.

What is the "the snoot effect"? It is a circle of light.

Then take cardboard, make a hole in the shape you need (a circle in this case) and mount it far from the light. Let's say 2 ft. You could use an additional light stand to hold it in place.

You probably need the cardboard to be black and flag de rest of the light spill with additional boards.

The truth is that the advantages of technology, led lights or spotlights are less heat. If that is the limitation of that light, use it for something else, such as a bounce light or something. Not all equipment is suitable for every purpose.

But it could be the case you like the [light cookie photography](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=light%20cookie%20photography) technique a lot, and you will start making shadows of other shapes. Blinds, tree foliage, windows, etc.